# Controlling Remote Processes from Linux Access Server

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, web-hosting, lxc

I have constructed a HA web cluster in LXD with each major service run within its own container. I.e, 2 x Nginx servers in a container each, 2 x MySQL etc.

I would like to add a management container that I can ssh to, issue commands, for example, `service nginx restart` and have the command redirected to the appropriate container, the Nginx servers in this case.

The closest thing I have found is OpenShift but given that I don't want to create a full blown PaaS I would prefer to find something more lightweight.

Is what I want to achieve possible?

Comment: You need something that can handle orchestration. Ansible is great for this task, and can also take care of configuration management and deployment for you as well if desired.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Ansible's cheapest package is $5000/year. This is something that will probably never scale past 10 virtual nodes and 2 physical servers so would ideally like a much less expensive solution.

Comment: No, no. That's their "Ansible Tower" hosted service. Their core configuration management/orchestration software is very much free: https://github.com/ansible/ansible